# How to diplay in xml without using create method?

Tags: odoo

Can I display data from the database without using the create method?
Only a view in a tree views and after modification I use create method to persist in the database.

Comment: What is the use case for needing to do this? Can you explain the need and process with more detail?

Comment: To display data from the database you don't need `create` method. Do you mean how to insert data into the database without using ORM `create` method?

Comment: yes to insert data without using ORM create method, but these data are in the base I display them like i want with some other data, after I insert them (like the joins)